# Not able to Pull installed Package metadata(components) using SFDX commands

Tags: salesforcedx, installedpackage

I have installed package in Scratch org, can someone please tell me how can I pull installed package metadata from Scratch org using SFDX command?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "pull" those components, because they are not Source Tracked in the usual manner. You can, however, use `sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Package Name"` to pull all available source from the package to your local copy. However, if this is a managed package, you won't be able to see any protected code from the installed package.